# Rails flexible opening times for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model `Garage` which should have opening times. But the opening times should be quite flexible. For example it could have different times for each day in the week and it should be possible to add breaks. But it could also be possible that the time does not differ or only for some days.

Now I wonder what would be a good way to implement this. Any ideas? I'm stuck for some days with this now :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the answers so far address the problem at all. Just thinking on my feet but I might have a schema like this (with example data):

```
id | garage_id | date       | week_day | start_time | end_time
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  |        10 |       NULL |        0 |       NULL |    NULL
2  |        10 |       NULL |        1 |      09:00 |   17:30
3  |        10 |       NULL |        2 |      09:00 |   17:30
4  |        10 |       NULL |        3 |      09:00 |   17:30
5  |        10 |       NULL |        4 |      09:00 |   17:30
6  |        10 |       NULL |        5 |      09:00 |   17:00
7  |        10 |       NULL |        6 |      11:00 |   16:00
8  |        10 | 2013-12-25 |     NULL |       NULL |    NULL
```

This example shows opening times for every day of the week, and an exception where the garage is closed on Christmas day. The application logic will give preference to `OpeningTimes` with the `date` column specified, and then revert to `week_day` if no matching column for `date` is found.

```
def is_open?
  if (exc = opening_times.find_by_date(Date.today))
    (exc.start_time..exc.end_time).cover?(Time.now)
  else
    tdy = opening_times.find_by_week_day(Date.today.wday)
    (tdy.start_time..tdy.end_time).cover?(Time.now)
  end
end
```

I think this provides the flexibility you're after.

Comment: Added an example implementation of an `is_open?` function.

Answer (score 1):

From a model standpoint, go simple:

- A Garage `has_many opening_times`
- Each OpeningTime has a `from` time and `until` time (like from 6am to 8pm)

As far as repetition, like if you want to repeat times on certain days, you can maybe use checkboxes -- for example, you can have a time slot (e.g. 6am - 8pm) and have check boxes next to which days you want to apply that time slot to. This would be a UX thing more than a backend thing.

Comment: An `OpeningTime` model was my idea, too and as you said I am thinking mostly about the UX thing. But how many opening times does a garage get then? One for each day or should they be combined somehow if the times are the same?

Comment: Well, I can't be 100% sure because I don't know your application, but it seems like grouping times together is of most relevance only when creating opening times. If this is the case, there's no real need to make an extra undertaking to group them together on the backend.

Comment: As for your first question, I'd guess a garage would have ~7 opening times, ~1 per day. You can have some Javascript or something helping users out creating repeated opening times, but don't reflect groups in your backend unless needed. If needed, you can make an `OpeningTimeGroup` model, and let garages `has_many` of those.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using mongoid syntax to include the fields and types:

```
class Garage
  has_many :days
end

class Day
  field :start, type: Datetime
  field :end, type: Datetime
  field :state, type: String, default: 'opened'

  belongs_to :garage

  def initialize(state, start, end)
    @state = state
    @start = start
    @end = end
  end
end
```